# $wpdb->get_results not returning an array

Tags: wpdb

I haven't really messed with $wpdb before, but I'm stuck hard on one part. I'm trying to get the values returned in an associative array.

I've tried both of these

```
$datarow = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT class_name FROM wp_wcs2_class WHERE id=$classnumber");
$datarow = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT class_name FROM wp_wcs2_class WHERE id=$classnumber",ARRAY_A);
```

but `print_r $datarow;` just errors out with `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE`

Any idea what's going wrong? I know the data is there because this returns the correct value:

```
$nameresult = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT class_name FROM wp_wcs2_class WHERE id=$classnumber",ARRAY_A));
```

Comment: Please echo the query and check for the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with `$wpdb`. It's PHP parse error.

`print_r` is a function, so you can't do `print_r $datarow;`
You should use `print_r( $datarow );` instead.

Comment: Lol, wow. A half hour, just to find out it's time for bed. Thanks mate! I'll mark it as answer in 7 mins when it lets me